# Trying to figure out how to force Aquamacs (or any windowed Emacs) to use the xterm 256-colors

Tags: emacs, aquamacs

This question is in regards to forcing emacs to use a 256 color xterm color scheme.

When you open emacs in a terminal that supports xterm-256, it defaults to the xterm-256 color scheme, where default emacs font face colors like 'Firebrick' turns into something the xterm color scheme can display, which in this case is 'Red', so on and so forth.  I really like this.  I do not like the default emacs colors in a non-terminal setting; I think they are too faded and washed out-- I much prefer the brightness of the terminal colors.

(In fact I find myself programming in the terminal most often simply because I vastly prefer the typeface and the colors-- but I'd like to start using Aquamacs more for various reasons.)

For the life of me, I cannot figure out how to force Emacs (or in my case, Aquamacs) to force itself to downgrade the default color scheme to the xterm 256 color scheme like it does in my terminal.  There has to be an easier way than making a new, ridiculously detailed color theme, but beyond the "TERM= " command you can set in your bashrc file (which obviously Aquamacs doesn't care about or use) I can't find anything equivalent in Emacs/Aquamacs that tells it to adopt a 256 color range so that it does things like turns Firebrick into the closest 'available' color, in this case, red.

I've attached screenshots.  The first is how I want it to look like.  (jpeg ruins the cripsness/brightness of the colors, but you get the idea.)

[image]

Second shot here is the default 'washed out' colors in aquamacs.  See how the comments are in Firebrick (correctly displayed), versus the bright red of the comments in the above pic.

[image]

Variable names show up as more yellow in the top pic, but as more 'brown' in the bottom.  Strings in the above file show up as more 'light brown' whereas in the bottom, it's more a dark brown.  You can see they are definitely the same color scheme-- it's just that the terminal doesn't know about some of the colors and so it converts them to their baser, brighter forms.

Anybody know how to force this in Aquamacs?  I've spent far too many hours researching this.  :-)

Thanks!
Nick